# Using certain rows as columns to create DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame *DF* looking like

```
DF =

     Date            Counterparty    Amount
0    2014-08-25      A               100
1    2014-08-25      A               200   
2    2014-08-25      B               300   
3    2014-08-26      C               400 
4    2014-08-27      C               500  
5    2014-08-27      A               600
6    2014-08-29      D               1000
```

I want to somehow create a new data frame *DF_new*, with (unique) columns as of the rows of *DF*:s column *'Counterparty'* with aggregated amounts from column *'Amount'*. In code, a result looking like

```
DF_new =

     Date            A            B            C            D
0    2014-08-25      300          300          0            0
1    2014-08-26      0            0            400          0      
2    2014-08-27      600          0            500          0      
3    2014-08-29      0            0            0            1000
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) method

```
In [41]: df.pivot_table(
             values='Amount', rows=['Date'], 
             cols=['Counterparty'], aggfunc='sum', 
             fill_value=0)
Out[41]: 
Counterparty    A    B    C     D
Date                             
2014-08-25    300  300    0     0
2014-08-26      0    0  400     0
2014-08-27    600    0  500     0
2014-08-29      0    0    0  1000
```